# How to create Login with Facebook or twitter in ios6 iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter

I am very new in iOS development.In my app,homepage is for login to the app.Where i need to give facility to login with Facebook and twitter. I am using iOS 6.1 and there i have social framework.

Please tell me an easy way to achieve this,i have tried to read facebook developer tutorial, but i am not able to catch from there.

If you have any sample project or any good tutorial link,please share with me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: for ios download the facebook sdk's it is the easy way to implement and it also works for ios<6. here http://developers.facebook.com/ios/ and they have pretty good examples

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook sdk github repo is [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) .

You can find many example projects in it.
Also Facebook [authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) guide explains the login part very clearly.